# Homogeneous space and rational section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let's embed $\operatorname{SO}_n$ inside $\operatorname{GL}_n$ through the standard representation. Does the map $\operatorname{GL}_n\rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_n/{\operatorname{SO}_n}$ admit a rational section?

Comment: A different wording of the same question:  is there a way to make a distinguished choice of one basis from every rotation class of bases?

Comment: No that is not true, even when the ground field is algebraically closed of characteristic zero.  A generic quadratic form is not isotropic.  There are many proofs.  I like the proof where you prove that the index equals two for the generic quadratic hypersurface in projective space.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a reference for it?

Comment: I do not have an immediate reference.  The proof that I am suggesting should be equivalent to computing that the Brauer group of the classifying stack of $\textbf{SO}_n$ is nontrivial.  This reduces to a computation in group cohomology, so I am sure that it is in the literature, but I am not sure where -- maybe the Book of Involutions?

Comment: A quick scan suggests that the element in the Brauer group of the stack that I mean is the same as that defined in Section 10.F of the Book of Involutions.  They do not compute this element in the case of the generic quadratic form in that section . . .

Comment: . . . This invariant is also described on the Wiki page for orthogonal groups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Galois_cohomology_and_orthogonal_groups

Comment: what confuses me is that it seems to me that the space of non-degenerate quadratic forms is rather GL_n/O_n instead of GL_n/SO_n.

Comment: As an algebraic group. $\textbf{GL}_n$ is a semidirect product of the normal subgroup $\textbf{SL}_n$ and a one-dimensional torus isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_m$, e.g., the subgroup of diagonal matrices such that every diagonal entry after the first equals $1$.  Thus, as a variety $\textbf{GL}_n/\textbf{SO}_n$ is isomorphic to the product of $\mathbb{G}_m$ and $\textbf{SL}_n/\textbf{SO}_n$.  Using the semidirect product structure, every rational section over $\textbf{GL}_n/\textbf{SO}_n$ gives a rational section over $\textbf{SL}_n/\textbf{SO}_n$, which does not exist by the Brauer invariant.